# List all the active branches in Git remote

Tags: git, git-branch

I am looking for a way to list all the active branches that are available on remote git repository.  I tried:

```
git branch -r
```

But this listed the already deleted branches as well.  I do not want the list to display deleted branches.

Comment: Did you try running `git fetch` on that remote first? Also `--prune` option can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I see remote branches which were deleted already?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351508/why-do-i-see-remote-branches-which-were-deleted-already)

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507435/git-branch-is-still-seen-after-merging-and-deleting-branches-under-remote-branch

Comment: What distinguishes an "active branch" from any other branch? That seems like it would be highly specific to a particular project, and thus not something that `git` really knows anything about...

Comment: @GreenOlvi I understand that --prune might solve my problem, but I am looking for a cleaner way to list all active branches with just one command and without any dependency on the state of my local repository.

Comment: You had selected the right answer.

Answer (score 24):

You can try (using [`git ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)):

```
git ls-remote --heads origin
```

That would list the branches directly from the remote repo. No fetch necessary.

Comment: If by active branch, we mean branches that exist on the remote, then it does list the active ones.

Comment: this is what i was looking for. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 13):

If someone arrives here looking for 'active branches' as branches that have not been merged in remote:

```
git branch -r --no-merged
```

Comment: If you're in a feature branch, then running this command won't show you the current branch itself. If you want to list all branches that haven't been merged to your `main` branch, including the current branch, you can run: `git branch -r --no-merged main` as documented [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---no-mergedltcommitgt)

Answer (score 6):

Try `git remote show origin` (or any other remote repository). Use `git remote prune origin` to get rid of deleted branches.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a main directory(parent) not in git 
And multiple sub directories that are in git 
The git cmd line will not work from the parent dir.
But this will. Listing all the sub directories and their active branches.

Run from parent dir.
for i in `ls -l | grep ^d|cut -d':' -f2|cut -d ' ' -f2`; do cd $i ;echo $i ;git branch; cd ..; done